# how to put two guests in two different hosts in the same LAN

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, vmware

I am using VMWare 12 Workstation, and have this setup:

- "Desktop HOST" with "VMware GUEST 1"

  - Desktop IP: 192.168.100.21
  - "VMware GUEST 1" IP: 192.168.200.21
- "Notebook HOST" with "VMware GUEST 2"

  - Notebook IP: 192.168.100.22
  - "VMware GUEST 1" IP: 192.168.200.22
- and one WiFi router in the Desktop, accessed by the Notebook
- all computers running Windows 10 Enterprise (it's free for 90 days...).
- all IP's are static

How can I configure my setup to have the two virtual machines comunicating with each other, copying files, transfering data, and using the "VMWare GUEST 1" as server and "VMWare GUEST 2" as test enviroment ?

Comment: You should bridge them to the same Network (VMnet)

Comment: What sort of communication are you looking for?

Comment: copying files, transfering data, and using the "VMWare GUEST 1" as server and "VMWare GUEST 2" as test enviroment

Answer (score 0):

The answer is a bit longer, so I will try to resume and add important links.

You need a [Bridge Network](https://www.lifewire.com/how-network-bridges-work-816357)

> A network bridge helps to join two otherwise separate computer networks together to enable communication between them

As you are Using a virtual network, use a virtual bridge:

1. You will use the Network Editor:

   - You can use the virtual network editor to view and change key networking settings
   - https://pubs.vmware.com/workstation-12/index.jsp#com.vmware.ws.using.doc/GUID-AC956B17-30BA-45F7-9A39-DCCB96B0A713.html
2. Virtual Bridge:

   - If you installed Workstation Pro on a host system that has multiple network adapters, you can configure multiple bridged networks.
   - When you configure bridged networking, the virtual machine uses physical network adapters on the host system to connect a network
   - https://pubs.vmware.com/workstation-12/index.jsp#com.vmware.ws.using.doc/GUID-D05850F8-E850-4086-A735-5C84C72D007C.html
3. From [VMware Knowledge Base](https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1018697)

   - https://youtu.be/AGeIJzrZpck

More reading: http://www.windowscentral.com/how-set-and-manage-network-bridge-connection-windows-10

Answer (score 0):

From [Virtuabox Manual](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html):

Bridged networking

This is for more advanced networking needs such as network simulations and running servers in a guest. When enabled, VirtualBox connects to one of your installed network cards and exchanges network packets directly, circumventing your host operating system's network stack.

If you have difficult with VMWare, try Virtualbox:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TtAd5vNRAck

Answer (score -1):

Using these two links you will get more about bridge network and network editor:

https://www.google.com.br/search?q=u:vmware+how+to+set+up+bridged+network

https://www.google.com.br/search?q=u:vmware+virtual+network+editor